# Why do some people oppose Tav haYosher?

Tags: food, hechsher-certification, mussar-ethics, employment, business

Is there a halachic reason to be opposed to Uri L'Tzedek and Tav haYosher? Why do some frum Jews oppose it?

Really the only things that I can find is that Uri L'Tzedek is left-wing and led by [YCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCT) rabbis, but this particular project of theirs seems to me like it should be relatively uncontroversial.

I know this is not the case, though, because a number of restaurants have refused the Tav simply because they think that it will be bad for business.

Information about Uri L'Tzedek:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uri_L%27Tzedek), 
[homepage](http://www.utzedek.org/)

Tav HaYosher:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tav_HaYosher), [homepage](http://www.utzedek.org/tavhayosher.html)

Comment: http://www.utzedek.org/ Uri L'Tzedek is a (modern) Orthodox social action organization. Tav HaYosher is their certification that the employees of a restaurant are treated fairly and paid a fair salary. This certification does not certify kashrut and is only given to restaurants that already have valid kosher certification.

Comment: That description is my biased version. There is some controversy about them, but I simply cannot find what the controversy is over or why anybody opposes them. Many Orthodox Jews (Haredi and otherwise) have a problem with them, and I'm wondering what the reason is.

Comment: I believe that the problem was originally that the standards of treatment were becoming mixed in with the notion of being "kosher". While there are laws about treating employees, they are completely separate from dietary laws and many people resisted adding another level to kashrut certification. In an iteration as an adjunct to standard kashrut I would think that there would be less opposition, but at first the ethical treatment of people was being folded in as a sine qua non of kashrut certification.

Comment: @Dan As far as I know, having the Tav was never supposed to be a requirement for kashrut. And that certainly isn't the case now, but people still oppose it. It is merely an indication that the restaurant treats its employees fairly. Someone who chooses to eat at restaurants with the Tav are doing so for capitalist reasons rather than kosher reasons.

Comment: @Daniel, could you add information (or links to same) to your question about what these are and something about what the issue is?  (I see you've done some of this in comments, but the question is a better place for that information -- easier to read, and comments can be deleted without leaving a revision history.)  Thanks.

Comment: Until you demonstrate that some people are opposed, maybe you should ask in a way that doesn't presuppose there is a problem, like "Is this a good thing?" "What are the reasons to support or oppose?"

Comment: @Daniel i know little about the history and development of these particular hechsherim, but here is the agudah's reposnse to the conservative movement's equivalent mark for ethical treatment. http://www.vosizneias.com/82934/2011/05/03/new-york-agudath-israel-new-hechsher-%E2%80%9Cmagen-tzedek%E2%80%9D-a-falsification-of-true-judaism I assume that some of the response which you ask about (though I am unfamiliar with that response as well) is rooted in similar ideas.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: How's this? Better?

Comment: @Dan I am familiar with the Conservative movement's similar mark, but I actually think that the situation is different here because the Convservative actually did hope to make that like a higher level of kashrut

Comment: @Daniel that was the concern (which some from the conservative movement rejected -- this was only to go on a product with pre-existing certification). The agudah article takes issue with that possible implementation but I don't think that that was clearly the case.

Comment: You still haven't demonstrated that anyone does oppose it.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for adding the links; that's better.  Could you add something about the opposition you're talking about?  What form does it take?  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I have to admit, I can't really find anything online about the opposition. That's why I'm kind of confused. I know it exists, though, because I know many people who have a strong disdain for Uri L'Tzedek and their programs. There are also plenty of articles online claiming that there is a controversy, but never actually discussing it. I guess I'm trying to find out what the controversy is all about.

Comment: @msh210: I understand how that is related, but I don't think it's really applicable here since this certification isn't a halachic one per se. It's really just a certification that the food meets a certain modern ethical standard and a person may choose not to eat only food with that certification without any halachic ramifications. People who do choose to limit their food intake to foods with the Tav do so independently of halacha (at least kashrut).

Comment: After looking over their website I can see people being opposed to them picking on companies and protesting against them for not meeting their criteria.

Comment: @GershonGold they don't actually protest companies that don't meet their criteria - it's only a yes list, not a no list.

Comment: I think you may have to ask the opposers rather than an online forum.

Comment: @Daniel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18021/why-do-some-people-oppose-tav-hayosher#comment42614_18026

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman- On their website they are clearly protesting against a Jewish company that they feel is not up to par.

Comment: @GershonGold: so you think that the reason people don't like them is for political rather than religious reasons? That could make sense. Although I don't really understand why it's generally the more right-wing people who oppose them.

Comment: @Daniel: As I said that might be a reason.

Comment: See http://www.cross-currents.com/archives/2012/02/17/when-tzedek-isnt-the-conservative-movement-finds-a-cause/

Comment: http://www.haaretz.com/news/national/.premium-1.550413

Comment: @Menachem I can't read the full story because I do not have a premium account at haaretz, but Uri Letzedek, the organization that gives the Tav Hayosher is an Orthodox, not Conservative organization (albeit, a rather liberal Orthodox organization). Furthermore, the Tav HaYosher is only given to restaurants that already have an Orthodox hechsher. It is not intended to certify kashrut. Only the ethical standards of the restaurant.

Comment: @Daniel: here is a copy of the same story: http://privateinvesigations.blogspot.com/2013/10/rabbinate-wine-made-under-conservative.html -- I thought magen tzedek and uri letzedek were the same thing

Comment: @Menachem No, Magen Tzedek *is* indeed a Conservative organization. Uri L'tzedek is an organization started by former YCT head Rabbi Avi Weiss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from ["Rubashkin Revenge: Ethical Certificates at Center of Dispute" (Jewish Journal, Los Angeles, July 25, 2012](http://www.jewishjournal.com/los_angeles/article/rubashkin_revenge_ethical_certificates_at_center_of_dispute_20120725/):

> Although the pushback against the Tav appears to be coming primarily, if not exclusively, from individuals affiliated with the Chabad Lubavitch movement, there is no evidence that any official encouragement came from Chabad, according to the organization’s leaders and those involved in the anti-Tav efforts. 
>   ...
>
> The issue appears not to be the Tav certification, per se, but rather that in 2008, Uri L’Tzedek was the instigator of a boycott of products from the Agriprocessors meat processing plant in Postville, Iowa, in the wake of the massive immigration raid that closed down the plant.

Comment: +1 This is actually a sourced answer! Can anyone clarify when Tav certification began?

Comment: "Uri L’Tzedek established the Tav Hayosher in 2009 as a free certification. To qualify, employers must demonstrate that they calculate worker’s hours accurately, pay wages—including overtime – promptly and in full and grant breaks to their employees, as required by law. Studies have shown that many food-service businesses – both kosher and non—fall short of these basic legal requirements."

Comment: It began shortly after the rubashkin incident, in response to it.

Comment: @SethJ So the Tav itself was never involved in the Rubashkin affair, so any complaints against it based on Rubashkin are really against the parent organization, Uri L'Tzedek. That is in my mind an important distinction.

Comment: @DoubleAA, so it seems, although I don't know how you can distinguish the two. Uri L'Tzedek is the organization; the Tav is a program of said organization. It's like saying don't boycott/support (take your pick) Chick-fil-a because of the political stance of the owner. It's the only way you can make your opinion known. If a person/organization takes a public stance on something you support/oppose, then supporting/boycotting said person/organization's public activities is the legitimate response.

Comment: FTR, I still don't think the question in its current form is particularly well suited to Mi Yodeya.

Comment: @SethJ Boycotting may be appropriate, but you should be upfront about what you're boycotting: people who boycott. You shouldn't make up new stuff about hechsherim and whatever. Say you are boycotting everything this organization does because you disagree with a previous boycott of theirs.

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't make stuff up, and I also think that you should remain calm so your message doesn't get garbled and TPYED OUTWITH splling miSTAKES and random CAPS. (Of course, none of that happens here; I'm speaking generally.) In any case, I still think that it's appropriate to boycott the primary activities of an organization whose other(/past) activities (have) offend(ed) you.

Comment: Regardless of whether the position makes sense, this does seem like it is a reason why people oppose the Tav. Therefore, I am accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You ask two questions:

> Is there a halachic reason to be opposed to Uri L'Tzedek and Tav haYosher? Why do some frum Jews oppose it?

I cannot answer the first. As to the second, the culture of the orthodox Jewish community is that it is resistant to change and that new trends tend to meet opposition at first. Here, for example, rabbis for centuries, and (more relevantly) even rabbis of last century, had seemingly not seen a need for such certification, so it can be viewed as not necessary. Moreover, it may be seen (even if inaccurately) as imposing rules (the certification's criteria) over and above *halacha*, which is often viewed as repugnant. Finally, the identities of the people who started it is no saving grace: had a *gadol hador* started the *tav*, a greater number of orthodox people may have acceded to his judgement as steeped in *Tora*.

I'm not passing judgement on the *validity* of these views (perhaps they are valid, perhaps not). You asked why some "frum" Jews oppose it, and this is my conjecture.

(Compare [a similar though not identical answer about confirmation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17055).)

Comment: See my comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18021/why-do-some-people-oppose-tav-hayosher#comment42610_18021 I think this may be different.

Comment: @SethJ, good point. The "Why do some frum Jews oppose it?" part of the question may be unanswerable. Perhaps it should be excised from the question, leaving only the halachic question?

Comment: Or he could ask if there are any published statements providing justification for opposition.

Comment: I like @SethJ 's suggestion.

Comment: There now seems to be [limited] information online about the opposition. Actually, I wonder if that article I quoted from was what inspired this question.

Comment: @SethJ As a matter of fact, it was complete coincidence that that article was published on exactly the same day I asked this question. I hadn't seen it before asking.

Answer (score 2):

There was an initiative very similar to this from non-halachic groups, and in general an objection raised about a non-Torah true organization imposing requirements in the guise of a hechsher. Perhaps there is perception that the objection raised in that case apply here. I am not informed if the same issues apply here or not. They inlcude: Being founded following the Rubashkin incident, where the charges were not found to be have veracity - so therefore founded in falsehood; The certification being focused on food establishents, (and only kosher ones)- where if it was genuinly interested in ethical standards should apply to any business, such as clothing manufacturers; Would harm the kashrus standards, confuse companies who would be expected to carry a second certification; Is assuming the role of enforcing or making statments on enforcement of regulations already managed by local, state, federal labor laws and government enforcement agencies.

Comment: Didn't the Rubashkin company plead guilty to 80 or so counts of something?

Comment: I am sure that they would love to focus on clothing manufacturers, etc. but my understanding is that they are a somewhat small organization.

Answer (score -5):

The Tav was founded on lies against Rubashkin. the Tav was given information by the Union, Rubashkin was found not guilty on the child labor charges which proves the Tav can make up lies on business owners.

Legal authorities of the land are already in-place, the Tav Heksher makes it seem that Jews will under-pay employees. That is why many kosher eateries wont accept the Tav and their bullies, which started on lies agains Rubashkin.

Comment: Rubashkin was found guilty of 86 counts of fraud. He was acquitted of the child labor charges because he might not have known about them, but Agriprocessors as a corporation pleaded guilty to child labor charges as well. (The results of the court cases are available on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholom_Rubashkin).)

Comment: @TheFedexGuy A source for any of your claims would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you assume that the Tav is only given on Jewish owned restaurants? People will not assume that Jews underpay; they will assume that Jews care to stop *anyone's* underpaying their workers, even the non-Jewish owners of restaurants.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin: Thank you! That is a real answer to this question (and I think a more relevant one than the the answer you gave above, actually)

Comment: @DoubleAA, the Tav lists on their website only Jewish owned eateries. Targeting only Jews, thank you Mendy Cohen for this awarness to boycott anyone at uses Tav which under mines the Legal system. And to eatery owners keep it simple you don't need boycotts, the legal authorities are in-charge not tav bullies.

Comment: @TheFedexGuy It's quite clear you don't like the Tav, but that doesn't mean you have to lie. A cursory look at [the list on their website](http://www.utzedek.org/tavhayosher/restaurant-listmap.html) shows a number of restaurants that are part of larger chains and are not Jewish owned, such as 16 Handles in Manhattan and the Doubletree Hotel in Chicago. Please stick to the facts. And by the way I'm still waiting on sources that show that the Tav are 'bullies' and 'make up lies'.

Comment: @DoubleAA Rubashkin is a prime example of how Uri Lttzedek boycotted Rubashkin and acted like bullies, Rubashkin Never knew there were Under ager employee and he was even found NOT guilty of this accusation, yet the bullies from Uri Letzedek, Morris Alen, Shmarya Rosenberg (the grandson of a well known Mobster) boycotted Rubashkin. also read wikipedia: The Tav HaYosher is a certification mark offered, free of charge, to Kosher food establishments http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tav_HaYosher

Comment: @TheFedexGuy Actually they boycotted his company which was guilty of underage employment. He was personally found guilty as well of **86 counts of fraud** (you seem to forget this FACT). Also, based on that quote I see no requirement for the owner to be Jewish and I have already demonstrated conclusively that there is no such requirement, so your point about people assuming that Jews underpay is moot.

Comment: @DoubleAA everyone knows Sholom Rubashkin was found Guilty on 86 counts on FINANCIAL Fraud, no one is disputing this and we all know Sholom Rubashkin did everything he could NOT have under age employees as the Jury of his P E E R S agreed with him. you cannot stop the boycott against business that will use the bully tav hayosher we will continue to educate the masses about tav hayosher bullying, such as was done with Sholom Rubashkin, only tav hayosher, Morris Alan  and the grandson of a mobster hate Rubashkin. Mainstream Kosher eateries will stay far away from the Bullies @ tav hayoshar

Comment: @TheFedexGuy You just said nothing. You didn't disagree with anything I said. You advanced no additional proof to any of your points. Yet you pledged to continue fighting against the Tav in spite of everything.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, while this conversation going on here is well and good, if you would post your comment about them never bringing Rubashkin to a Beis Din first, I would like to accept that as the answer to this question.

Comment: @Daniel  Correct Morris Alen was parading Around Postville and the Media how Sholom Rubashkin was employing under age workers, yet in court this turned out  to be a farce, who is next from these Tav Bullies?!

Comment: @TheFedexGuy It wasn't a farce. He was employing them. It couldn't be proven that he knew he was employing them, but he definitely was employing them. Why do you keep lying?