# Is the Magen Tzedek for workers' living conditions?

Tags: halacha, mussar-ethics, employment, conservative-judaism

Recently I chanced across websites that describe the pitiful living conditions of (largely migrant) agricultural workers in various countries worldwide (e.g., China, Africa, Europe, Asia, North America - - see, for example [here](http://globalhealth.org/migrant-workers-right-to-health-a-global-advocacy-agenda/).)

Is this something that the Conservative [Magen Tzedek](http://www.magentzedek.org/) was designed to consider?  Why or why not (from a halachic perspective -  is such food forbidden for any reason)?  If so, is the Magen Tzedek program still operational?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18021/759

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50673/discussion-on-question-by-yehuda-w-is-the-magen-tzedek-for-workers-living-condi).

Comment: Here are the two people who would know if the program is active, and what if anything has been certified:
Rabbi Morris Allen, Program Director (Morris@magentzedek.org)
Harvey Popolow, Executive Director (harvey@magentzedek.org)

Comment: @Arieh I hesitate to contact the Program Director or Exec Dir. I little web search turned up a 2013 Forward article saying they did not have a single company signed up 4 years after they started (http://forward.com/news/176814/magen-tzedek-ethical-kosher-seal-stalled-amid-orth/). The "Latest News" on the magentzedek.org website is dated May 11, 2013.  A pity, since their standards look good.

Comment: Is this on-topic? It seems to address Jewish individuals rather than Judaism.

Comment: @DonielF I think it's on topic. It's tagged [conservative-judaism], and asks about the practices of their kashrus (?) organization. We've had questions about the practices of other *hashgachos* that weren't closed (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Shokhet Like what, questions about what they consider kosher? I find that to be different than why a random company that happens to deal with kashrus was founded.

Comment: @YehudaW Don't hesitate. Worse comes to worst you get a bounced email.

Comment: @DonielF That was already discussed [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34335646#34335646), and the edits to the question were meant to address it.

Comment: @DonielF " I find that to be different than why a random company that happens to deal with kashrus was founded" Agreed the only part of the question that is on topic IMO is "from a halachic perspective - is such food forbidden for any reason)". Regardless of whether or not the rest of the question is on topic, you can still vtc as too broad.

Comment: Thank you @mevaqesh. I was unaware of the history of this post.

Comment: @Shokhet You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

"In 2008, a commission was formed by prominent leaders of Conservative Judaism to develop and apply a set of standards that would certify that kosher food manufacturers in the US operate according to Jewish ethics and social values. The Commission formalized its status and organized as an Illinois not-for-profit corporation on January 31, 2011 and operates under IRS 501(c)3 status as the Magen Tzedek Commission NFP.:  See here: http://www.magentzedek.org/ and also here http://www.magentzedek.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/MT_standards.pdf

Comment: The standards seem impressive.  Is the Magen Tzedek program operational?  Is it evaluating and supervising?  Is it active?

Comment: "from a halachic perspective - is such food forbidden for any reason" It isn't really your fault that you didn't address this; more the fault of the OP for including too many questions in the post.

Comment: However, I don't see how this answers the other parts of the question either: whether it addresses worker conditions, and whether it is still operational.